# JQuery. How to take one value from xml?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have XML:

```
<note>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
</note>
```

Write on the jQuery:

```
xml = "<note><value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value></note>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$value = $xml.find("value");
alert($value.text());
```

Output: 123

How to output 1, 2, 3 by queue?

Answer (score 1):

The `$value` is a set of the `value` elements, so the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text) will return a combined text of all elements in the set.

Since you want to have each value separately, you can loop through the element set `$value` and process the value like

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();


xml = "<note><value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value></note>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$value = $xml.find("value");
$value = $xml.find("value");
$value.each(function() {
  log($(this).text());
  //alert($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
xml = "<note><value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value></note>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$value = $xml.find("value");
len=$value.length;
$value.each(function(index ){
    if(index != len-1)
        console.log($(this).text()+',');
        else
            console.log($(this).text());

  });
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/ox2f383t/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.map()` method to get an array of all the values, then to a comma-separated string, if desired:

```js
var xml = "<note><value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value></note>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $value = $xml.find("value"),
    values = $value.map(function(i,v) {
        return $(v).text();
    })
    .get()
    .join(', ');

$('.values').append( values );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="values"></div>'
```